# creating new object in R

Tags: r

I want to create a new object `new_cars` containing the columns `mpg, hp` from `mtcars` data set but column names should be `miles_p`, and `horse_p` respectively.

I used following code:

```
df=data.frame("miles_p"=mtcars$hp,"horse_p"=mtcars$mpg)
```

which creates a new data frame as follows
[output for df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivtXV.png)

the original `mtcars` object is as per follows

[original mtcars with two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDYUW.png)

original `mtcars` gives car's name initially, however in new object serial numbers are there initially.

What to do if we want that car names in new object as per `mtcars` instead of numbering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% select(hp, mpg)
names(df) <- c("miles_p", "horse_p")
```